# Can I style text that has been inserted via the "content" CSS attribute?

Tags: html, css, attributes, css-animations

I am animating a button using CSS and the ease animation, I have found out that i can insert text on top of the ease animation by using the "content" attribute. is there a way to style the text that is inserted?

or is there a better way to style and insert text? - would prefer to use just CSS please.

Comment: Please take a bit of time to read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question to increase the chances of getting good replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, see the example

```css
div {
position:relative;
width: 400px;
height: 50px;
}

div:after {
position: absolute;
content: 'inserted via CSS';
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

/* adding some random properties to illustrate */

background-color: maroon;
color: white;
text-decoration: underline;
font-size: 2em;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class=test></div>
```

Comment: thanks! this helped a lot, is there a way to place a button on top of the same animation? or am i limited to just inserting text?